# Elasticsearch is giving error with date on bulk insert

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to insert records in Elasticsearch using bulk api and I am getting below error

> "error": "MapperParsingException[failed to parse [created_date]]; nested: MapperParsingException[failed to parse date field [2015-07-18 13:00:22], tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: \"2015-07-18 13:00:22\" is malformed at \" 13:00:22\"]; "

while I am passing below date

> "created_date":"2015-07-18 13:00:22"

and below mapping is used

```
"created_date": {
"format": "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
"type": "date"
},
```

I can see that date is correct and mapping is also correct, error is giving for this particular record only and other records are inserted successfully. What could be the reason?

Comment: The correct format should be with lowercase `d`, like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your mapping has been applied to the field you are expecting.

Logs says `tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []`

It does not say that it tries `yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`.

May be your `created_date` is another `created_date` field?

Answer (score 0):

use "created_date":"2015-07-18T13:00:22"
It may help You